# Best polygon fitting into points

Tags: image-processing, graphics, 2d, polygon, point

I'm looking for an algorithm to find a polygon that can represent a set of points in 2D space. Specifically, if given a set of points like this

[image]

It should ideally produce something similar to this:

[image]

(The arrows are segments)

Basically, the output would be a set of segments that "best" address the features of the points. The algorithms possibly take some parameters to control the numbers of output segments.

I currently do not have any ideas on what algorithms I'm looking for. Any papers or advice are appreciated.

Comment: Any constraints? I think this is a similar problem to clustering: if you don’t know how many clusters there are, the problem becomes a whole lot more complex.

Comment: This might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55511236/7328782

Comment: @CrisLuengo That looks quite promising for my case. I'll look it up. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible algorithm.

For every point, look at the 2 points closest to it, they become connected.
Then use Douglas Peucker to refine the edges.

Essentially you will create a first polygon containing all the points, and the try to eliminate points whose elimination doesn't change the shape too much.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I'm looking for. Though I'm not sure connecting two points that are closest will work for the case that the two points are very close to each other but connecting them will divide the shape into two parts. Like a set of points form an "8" will result in two circles or something.

Comment: Unfortunately, heuristical algorithms are usually not perfect ofr every case.

Answer (score 1):

Completing @Makogan response an implementation of Douglas-Peucker algorithm can be found in [`approximate_polygon`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.approximate_polygon) function from [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/)

```py
from skimage.measure import approximate_polygon

approximate_polygon(<your_coordinates_numpy_array>)
>>> array([[x,y],...])
```

Some usage example can be found [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/edges/plot_polygon.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-edges-plot-polygon-py)